# UITableView - after didselect row to play Youtube video

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, youtube

Has anybody any idea how to make UITableView the way how it is done with Youtube app?
I mean, in the cells there are thumbnails and some text. This part I have already done.
But still cannot realize how to trigger video. I know how to trigger it from web view, but this is different case. 
any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: My observation is that the cells behave like UIWebViews in the native YT app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have use `UITableViewCell` for the cell template?

There is [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Overview:**

> A movie player (of type MPMoviePlayerController) manages the playback of a movie from a file or a network stream. Playback occurs in a view owned by the movie player and takes place either fullscreen or inline. You can incorporate a movie player’s view into a view hierarchy owned by your app, or use an MPMoviePlayerViewController object to manage the presentation for you

You can see also in the detail in [Apple's Multimedia Programming Guide by using Video](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW1) .

Comment: Basically I use standard way to create cells. And I have tried hte MPMOviePlayerController, but that's not the way. But tnx anyway.